# Real Analysis - Continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

(a) Give an example of a continuous function $f$ and a bounded
set $A$ such that $f(A)$ is not bounded.

(b) Give an example of a continuous function $f$ and an open, bounded set $A$ such
that $f(A)$ is not bounded.

(c) Give an example of a continuous function $f$ and an open, bounded set $A$ such
that $f(A)$ is not open.

(d) Give an example of a continuous function $f$ and an open, bounded set $A$ such
that $f(A)$ is neither open nor bounded.

For (a), I was thinking $f(x)=1/x$ on the bounded set $(0,1)$.

For (b), I was thinking $f(x)=\tan x$ on the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

I'm not sure about those answers or how to do to the rest.

Comment: So far so good, your answers are correct. What's the problem with (c) and (d)? What have you tried? Where did you stuck? Do you know what is a closed set in $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: For (c), don't you think a constant function work?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by (c) but for (d) i guess i could use f(x)=tanx but i dont know what the interval would be

Answer (score 1):

Your examples for $(a)$ and $(b)$ are correct.

For $(c)$, let $f(x) =1$ and $A = (-1,1)$. Then $f(A) = \{1\}$ is not open.

For $(d)$, consider $f(x) = \frac1{1-x^2}$ and $A = (-1, 1)$. Then $f(A) = [1,\infty)$ is neither open nor bounded.

Answer (score 0):

For (c), take a constant function $g:A\to\Bbb{R}$, say $g(x)=k\;\forall x\in A$ ($A$ can be whatever you want).

For (d), take the following function and think about it.

$f: A=(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})\to\Bbb{R}$ given by
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll} 0 & \text{if}& x\in (-\frac{\pi}{2},0] \\ \tan x & \text{if} & x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}) \end{array}\right. $$
Is $f$ continuous on $A$? What is $f(A)$?